# Vite + Vue 3 built project Content-Security-Policy Error (CSP) 'script-src "self"' because of new Function constructor in built files

Tags: vite, rollup, content-security-policy

I have added CSP header 'Content-Security-Policy': "script-src 'self'", built project, then got  error:

*Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".*

which disables using eval & Function constructors.  Is it possible to get rid of using Function constructor in built files?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, it wasn't problem of vue 3 itself. The problem was caused from
'vue-i18n' plugin which was solved by adding

```
__INTLIFY_JIT_COMPILATION__: true
```

to define object in vite.config.ts

[image]

https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/issues/1457